# Jump Game II Leetcode, why is my memoization failing?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem:

> ###### [Jump Game II](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/)
>
> Given an array of non-negative integers `nums`, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.
>
> Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that
> position.
>
> Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.
>
> You can assume that you can always reach the last index.

```
class Solution:
    def jump(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        memo = {}
        result = self.helper(0, nums, 0, memo)
        return result
    def helper(self, numJump, nums, currentInd, memo):
        if currentInd in memo:
            return memo[currentInd]
        if currentInd == len(nums) - 1:
            return numJump
        val = nums[currentInd]
        totalMin = float("inf")
        for ind in range(1, val + 1):
            newInd = currentInd + ind
            if newInd >= len(nums):
                continue
            ret = self.helper(numJump + 1, nums, newInd, memo)
            if ret < totalMin:
                totalMin = ret
        if currentInd not in memo:
            memo[currentInd] = totalMin
        return totalMin
```

My solution works without my cache. But as soon as I add it, I get incorrect input.

Here is an example:

- input = `[1,2,1,1,1]`
- expected output = `3`
- actual output = `4`

Comment: Describe the meaning of `helper` (in terms of its inputs and its output) and likely you'll realize what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you memoize the total steps from the beginning to the current index before all alternatives have been considered. After finding a first path to the end, we know that these distances might not be optimal yet, but still you store them in `memo`. As you then take an alternative route to get to the same point, you trust that `memo` to give you the optimal distance -- which is a wrong assumption.

The right way to memoize, is to store the number of steps *ahead*, as if the current index is the *starting* point. As this value is only stored when all alternatives starting at that index have been considered, this *is* an optimal value.

As you backtrack, add 1 step to what you get from the recursive call.

Here is your code adapted with that approach:

```
    def helper(self, nums, currentInd, memo):
        if currentInd in memo:
            return memo[currentInd]
        if currentInd == len(nums) - 1:
            return 0  # No more steps needed
        val = nums[currentInd]
        totalMin = float("inf")
        for ind in range(1, val + 1):
            newInd = currentInd + ind
            if newInd >= len(nums):
                break # No need to continue...
            ret = self.helper(nums, newInd, memo)
            if ret < totalMin:
                totalMin = ret
        memo[currentInd] = 1 + totalMin  # Add step taken
        return memo[currentInd]
```